# Wo steigen Sie ein? In Bonn oder in Köln?

Tags: verb

Can I say "Wo steigen Sie ein? In Bonn oder in Köln?"
My textbook only lists "Wo steigen Sie aus? In Bonn oder in Köln? " as correct.

Comment: `einsteigen` and `aussteigen` are separable verbs so called `tranbare verben`.  so it is completely right. Like `ich steige ein`, ich steige aus, ich steige um. e.g. Wo steigen Sie ein.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. Of course, "einsteigen" means "getting in" and "aussteigen" means "getting out/off", so you shouldn't use them as equals, but if you don't only want to know where someone gets off the train but also where he boards, "einsteigen" is the verb to go.

Answer (score 4):

To complement Dirk Liebhold's answer: you may also say:

> Wo steigen Sie **um**? In Bonn oder in Köln?

(Where will you change trains?)